# How to change the text of one JButton by clicking a second JButton in Java

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I want to change the text of one `JButton` when I click on the second `JButton`, but it's doing nothing. I don't know what is the problem is.
If anyone will help me as soon as possible then I would be really thankful and will appreciate every effort.

```
public class myJPanel6 extends JPanel implements ActionListener
{  

myJButton b1, b2;
student st1;
String s1;

public myJPanel6()
{

    setLayout(new GridLayout(1,1));

    student st1 = new student("Michael", "Robinson", 20);

    b1 = new myJButton(st1.getName());
    b1.addActionListener(this);
    add(b1);

    b2 = new myJButton(st1.WhatIsUp());
            b2.addActionListener(this);
    add(b2);
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

   if(e.getSource() == b1)
   {
       s1=st1.WhatIsUp();
       b2.setText(s1);
   }
}
```

Comment: whatisUp() is a method which have a text which is displaying on button, and that is located in the student class.

Comment: To get better help sooner, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or a [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org). Also take a look at the [Jave Naming Conventions](http://www.javatpoint.com/java-naming-conventions).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually you have two issues:

1. You declared `student` as local variable while its already defined as instance variable (shadowing); you should use the instance variable in your case.
2. Also, in your example, the `b2` is already having `WhatIsUp` value , so nothing will change; you should set it with name to be able to change the value of button one.  Check my below example for your full example.

Code:

```
package a.b.c;

import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class myJPanel6 extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
    JButton b1, b2;
    student st1;
    String s1;

    public myJPanel6() {
        setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1));

        st1 = new student("Michael", "Robinson", 20);
        b1 = new JButton(st1.getName());
        b1.addActionListener(this);
        add(b1);

        b2 = new JButton(st1.WhatIsUp());
        b2.addActionListener(this);
        add(b2);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource() == b1) {
            s1 = st1.getName();
            b2.setText(s1);

        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frm=new JFrame();
        frm.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        myJPanel6 pnl=new myJPanel6();
        frm.add(pnl);
        frm.pack();
        frm.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frm.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: actually i want that when i click on the first button, then the text on the second button changes every time when i click the first button. but my code is doing nothing.

Comment: I have updated your code to be able to work , check the code in my answer.

Comment: now it's work fine. now i want that every time i click the first button then image on the second button changes every time i click the first button.

Comment: Kindly accept this answer ,  and post another question  if you have another inquiry.

Comment: See also [*Initial Threads*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).

Comment: @NaveedAli : You can't keep asking (extending your case) that's not good, different inquiry should be put in a different question.